# How to debug apps with #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT statements on HoloLens

Tags: hololens

I was recently tinkering with HoloLens2 and read the code on Github about getting the RGB camera data stream from HoloLens2.I want to use debugging method to see how the program is running, but there is #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT statement in the code, according to the general Hololens application debugging method, I can't see the change of some parameters in the code, so please tell me how to debug the code running on HoloLens in this case. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this documentation to learn how to attach a managed debugger to your Unity IL2CPP UWP build on your HoloLens 2 to enable you setting breakpoints and debug C# code as usual: [Managed debugging with Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/managed-debugging-with-unity-il2cpp)

In short:

1. Check InternetClientServer and PrivateNetworkClientServer in the UWP Publishing Settings Capabilities
2. Check Development Build, Script Debugging, Wait for Managed Debugger (optional) in the Unity UWP build settings
3. Build in Unity.
4. Build and deploy from the Visual Studio solution to your device with the Debug or Release configurations.
5. Make sure your device is connected to the same network as your PC and start the app on your device and your device is not connected to your PC via USB.
6. Open any script in Unity and go to the Visual Studio solution that opens to view and edit.
7. Go to Debug -> Attach Unity Debugger.
8. Select your device from the list and click "OK" to attach.